# Como manter a página de um site no mesmo ponto que ela estava antes de atualizar?

Tags: php, html, formulário

Tenho uma páginha em html e php e coloquei um formulário no fim da página.

Quando clico no botão "enviar" a página atualiza e vai lá para cima.

Dessa forma o usuário tem que rolar toda hora até chegar embaixo novamente para ver se os dados foram cadastrados, se há uma mensagem de erro ...

```
 <form id="formulario" name="login" method="POST" 
 action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>">
```

No action eu tentei "PHP_SELF' também.

A estrutura é html, body e uma div, o formulário está dentro da div.

Comment: Pode mostrar a `action` do *form* e a estrutura básica do HTML?

Comment: É possível usar um `fragment` ou você possui algum requisito que não? No meu entendimento, esta é uma das funções dele.

Comment: @brasofilo add ai na pergunta

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira eu não tenho costume de usar fragment, vocÊ acha que isso pode resolver? Então vou pesquisar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser resolvido com uma `anchor` justo antes do `<form>`:

```
<a name="form-anchor"></a>
<form ETC...
```

E fazer a `action` do formulário ir para essa `anchor`:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>#form-anchor"
```

Testei com este PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #div-grande {
        background-color:#ddd;
        min-height: 3800px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-grande">
        <?php if( isset( $_POST['grafico'] ) ) echo 'POSTED<br />'; ?>
        Dummy 3800px height
    </div>
    <a name="form-anchor"></a>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>#form-anchor">
         <input type="submit" name="grafico" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coisa básica, mas não uso sempre ai não vem na mente nem com a desgrama. Muito obrigado e desculpa por perguntar coisa tão simples.

Comment: É da época do Windows 95 :)

Comment: Mas funciona perfeitamente, eu só coloquei a âncora mais abaixo porque tenho um monte de texto antes do form. Mais uma vez valeu. É porque estou trabalhando com banco de dados e tenho que deixar  a interface "legalzinha" com o CSS, ai fico azoado....

Comment: Um dia vou ser "psicopata" igual a vocÊ... pq lembrar do âncora e saber que tem que colocar naquele específico lugar dentro do action é froid,viu?

Comment: Agora eu sei também. :)

Comment: Tem a manha do filme Estômago? `Num tava ligado, não, mas agora eu tou!` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer é a seguinte:

Adicione um parametro na URL de envio de formulario. Por exemplo o parametro ?form=1

Adicione um id para o formulario, por exemplo #formulario. Baseado nessas configurações no php coloque esse código:

```
if ($_GET["form"] == "1") { 
    echo '<script> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            function scrollToAnchor("#formulario"){ 
                jQuery(\'html,body\').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(aid).offset().top - 119}, 700);       
            }           
            scrollToAnchor("#'.$_GET["url"].'"); 
        });
      </script>';  
}
```

Assim que o php verificar que a url tem o parametro de formulario ele vai adicionar um JS que vai rolar a página(com direito a animação) até a div que está o formulário.

OBS: Estou imaginando que você utilize a biblioteca jQuery.

Comment: Na verdade eu só uso javascript em último caso, mas muito obrigado, o @brasofilo me passou o que eu estava procurando. Coisa que a gente vê quando está estudando html, mas que na hora do sufoco...