# Estou com um problema ao carregar a pagina ela vai direto para o footer

Tags: html, jquery, css

Ao abrir a pagina no localhost ela vai direto para o footer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ela não começa no cabeçalho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema está no form, mas eu não faço ideia de pq..]
codigo:

```
 <form id="contact" action="mail_send.php" method="post">
    <h3>Precisa de Ajuda?</h3>
    <h4>Entraremos em contato em 24 horas úteis.</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Digite seu nome" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Digite seu email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Deixe o seu numero (Opicional)" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Digite sua mensagem ...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Enviando">Enviar</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

E quando eu dou f5 na pagina ela não vai para o topo da pagina ela continua fixa é normal isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, o problema é que você está ativando o `autofocus` no `input`, fazendo com que o navegador entenda que aquele campo está ativado pelo user, fazendo a página rolar direto a onde está, literalmente, o foco. Basta retirar que seu problema é resolvido.

Comment: Opa mano vlw, você sabe me dizer sobre isso de usar f5 e a pagina continuar no mesmo lugar e não voltar ao topo ou recarregar?

Comment: @Felipe, da uma olhada nessa pergunta aqui no Stack. [Como manter a página de um site no mesmo ponto que ela estava antes de atualizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38398/como-manter-a-p%C3%A1gina-de-um-site-no-mesmo-ponto-que-ela-estava-antes-de-atualizar)